# Clojure error calling a recursive function -- most likely a parentheses issue

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I am VERY green to Clojure. But I am trying to learn the syntax by creating some functions. I am having issues with the parentheses and syntax in general...

This function is supposed to take a list and a position and return the list with that position removed--but I am getting an error that I don't fully understand. I have done some reading and it seems like its an issue with nested parentheses.. but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

The error:

> ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPersistentCollection clojure.core/conj (core.clj:83)

The code:

```
(defn delete-at
"accepts a list and position--returns the list with
 value at that position removed"
(
[L, pos]
(cond
  (empty? L) nil
  (zero? pos) (rest L)
  :else (
          delete-at (first L) (rest L) (- pos 1))
  )
)
([L-new, L2, pos]
(cond
  (zero? pos) (conj L-new (rest L2))
  :else (
          (delete-at (conj L-new (first L2)) (rest L2) (- pos 1))
          )
  )
)
)
```

Comment: The parentheses in Clojure, or any other Lisp for that matter, are not the same as curly braces in any C-family language. The way you format your code seems to indicate that you believe they are. Take a look here: http://hitchhikersclojure.com/blog/hitchhikers-guide-to-clojure/ for an introduction to Clojure syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

giving it a pass through emacs' formatter makes the problem jump out to me: an extra set of `()` around the last call to delete-at and the arguments to the first conj call are reversed.

```
(defn delete-at
"accepts a list and position--returns the list with
 value at that position removed"
([L, pos]
 (cond
  (empty? L) nil
  (zero? pos) (rest L)
  :else (delete-at (first L) (rest L) (- pos 1))))
([L-new, L2, pos]
 (cond
  (zero? pos) (conj L-new (rest L2))
  :else ((delete-at (conj L-new (first L2)) (rest L2) (- pos 1))))))
```

when reading Clojure, lots of stacked closing parens `)))))` is normal and looks good to the eye (once you get used to it) and stacked opening parens `((` jumps out as suspicious. It mainly comes up when you are calling a function that returns a function, and then you want to call the resulting function.

```
user> (defn delete-at
 "accepts a list and position--returns the list with
  value at that position removed"
([L, pos]
 (cond
  (empty? L) nil
  (zero? pos) (rest L)
  :else (delete-at (first L) (rest L) (- pos 1))))
([L-new, L2, pos]
 (cond
  (zero? pos) (conj (rest L2) L-new)
  :else (delete-at (conj L-new (first L2)) (rest L2) (- pos 1)))))
#'user/delete-at
user> (delete-at [1 2 3] 1)
(1 3)
```

It's well worth getting emacs setup with [cider](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider), [clojure-mode](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode), and paredit (paredit is *very* useful and getting used to it is a bit of an accomplishment) This is a good place to start learning, and many people choose to use a starter kit of some sort such as [emacs starter](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit) kit or [emacs live](https://github.com/overtone/emacs-live)

Comment: just as a side note this can be written as `(concat (take (dec pos) l) (drop pos l))` amongst many other ways.